# Typescript How to access component variable in foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hey can somebody tell me how I can access a component variable in foreach loop ?
Here my
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7M3COcICuL3FMgmX3ZIq?p=preview)

```
 public testVariable:number;

  test(){
    console.log('fired');
    var x  =[1,2,3,4];

    x.forEach(function (e){
      this.testVariable = e;
    })

    console.log( this.testVariable);
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you use `function (e)`, the `this` inside it will refer to the function's scope instead of the class.

Use the `Arrow Function`(or `Fat Arrow`) instead:

```
x.forEach((e) => {
    this.testVariable = e;
})
```

When having only 1 parameter, you may also omit the parenthesis around it:

```
x.forEach(e => {
    this.testVariable = e;
})
```

Here's a good article explaining it's behavior: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: Won't the result of this always be `4`? Also, aren't all anonymous functions "lambda"s?

Comment: @evolutionxbox you are correct, lambda is a synonym for anonymous functions, I corrected the answer. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This was a big help.  The article is no longer available, but it seems like odd behavior.

Answer (score 7):

The value of `this` depends on the scope you're in. Consider doing it like this:

```
public testVariable:number;

test(){
    console.log('fired');
    var x  =[1,2,3,4];

    var self = this;
    x.forEach(function (e){
        self.testVariable = e;
    })

    console.log( this.testVariable);
}
```

Comment: Your implementation was necessary for es5, but is obsolete in typescript et al